# plotting the frequency of time in Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot

I have 180,000 lines in a csv file and the third column (Time) looks like this `2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00` (Time is in UTC). So how can I plot a graph in Python that can show how many of these lines(tweets) happened in each 5 minutes interval of the 2 hour time frame across the entire csv file? For example, I am interested in knowing how many tweets have happened in each 5 minutes interval.

Some sample lines from the CSV file looks like this:

```
Candidate,ID,Time,Username,Tweet
Clinton,788948653016842240,2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00,Tamayo_castle,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 
Clinton,788948666501464064,2016-10-20 03:43:14+00:00,ThinkCenter1968,Maecenas congue, sem nec suscipit aliquam, lorem enim pl
Clinton,788948673594097664,2016-10-20 03:43:16+00:00,21stCenRevolt,Curabitur nec condimentum lorem. Aliquam a dolor porta
Both,788948662881751040,2016-10-20 03:43:13+00:00,mikeywan,Ut eu sagittis metus. Phasellus ut vulputate dui, nec malesuada 
Both,788948675313696769,2016-10-20 03:43:16+00:00,erwoti,Fusce sit amet aliquet ipsum, quis placerat elit. 
Clinton,788948671756955650,2016-10-20 03:43:15+00:00,isaac_urner,te nisi, vitae bibendum odio. Maecenas hen
```

Basically, I am not sure how to link the pd.date_range below to tweets_df so that it could show the frequency of tweets in 5 minutes intervals over a two hour period (say in histogram format or any other representative plot).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_df = pd.read_csv('valid_tweets.csv')
print(tweets_df)
pd.date_range('10/20/2016 1:55', '10/20/2016 3:55',
              freq='5 min', tz='UTC')
```

Comment: 1) read the csv with pandas, making sure to parse the dates, 2) resample to a 5-min frequency and apply the `count` method, 3) use the `plot` method of the resulting dataframe

Comment: also, lovely sample content you've provided us with :(

Comment: Well, that's my research and how I got funded :D

Comment: I switched it over to filler content

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have gotten lots of votes down previously because of not providing sample CSV so thought to provide a few lines though didn't know your method. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would do this with pandas >= 0.19:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FIVEMIN = pandas.offsets.Minute(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3.5))

ax = (
    pandas.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['Time'])
          .resample(FIVEMIN, on='Time')['ID']
          .count()
          .plot.line(ax=ax) 
)
plt.show()
```

If you're not on pandas 0.19 or higher, you'll need to explicitly set the index:

```
ax = (
    pandas.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['Time'])
          .set_index('Time') 
          .resample(FIVEMIN)['ID']
          .count()
          .plot.line(ax=ax) 
)
```

Comment: in pandas 0.20.3 I got this error .resample(FIVEMIN, by='Time')
TypeError: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

Comment: @MonaJalal oh oops, you group *by* a column, but resample *on* a column. see the edit

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YFLbFU3i File "/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4755, in <listcomp>
    items = [func(x) for x in index]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: take out the `rename` command. I though `count` returned a series, but apparently it acts on all columns

Comment: hey now that my time has changed to Eastern, your code gives me error:
2016-10-19 23:43:16-04:00
Do you know how to fix this? https://paste.linux.community/view/a25a0fa5

Comment: @MonaJalal a buffer overflow could be a lot of things. Try not parsing the times to see if it goes through. If that works, you'll need to write your own date parser to handle the format you're using